# Code signing issues

Tags: permissions, ssl, code

I have purchased a certificate from godaddy, which is now in `.pfx` format. I tried to convert it into `.cer` using Internet Explorer and Firefox. I tried to to sign midlet using converted `.cer`, but I get following error message:

> The KeyStore does not contain private key associated with this alias !! Cannot sign

How to get work done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403174/convert-pfx-to-cer) on this with a OpenSSL based answer.

from there,

```
openssl pkcs12 -in xxxx.pfx -out mycertificates.crt -nokeys -clcerts
```

Comment: "java.security.cert.certificateParsingException Invalid der encoded data."

getting this message.

Comment: i tried doing this but when i select export private key , i am getting .cer (DER encoded) option disabled . and midletsigner utility need provatekey anyhow..

Comment: solved this issue with..



Keytool –importkeystore –srckeystore “The_Name_Of_The_PFX_file.PFX”
–destkeystore Name_For_The_Key_store.jks –srcstoretype PKCS12 –
deststoretype JKS

Comment: now midlet is signed..but root certificate is not there in device i think as its showing domain as :"Untrusted"

Comment: i have installed its root certificate certificate..

using this 
symcaimport.redelijkheid.com/

now 
settings>security>certificates>godaddy>select use>

there are three options

server auth.
cross certi.
app signing


among which app sign is disabled.. 


and when i install the app and click on it it shows invalid application "Delete ?" 


rot certificate i have installed is from 
https://certs.godaddy.com/anonymous/repository.seam
Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority Root Certificate (DER Format)